# Execute result of a PostgreSQL query again to get the final result set?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-11

I'm looking for a way to get the list of all json attributes across all my PostgreSQL tables dynamically.

I have Query 1 which would generate a list of sql statements, and then run that sql statements to get the final output all in one go (like the dynamic SQL concept in SQL server).

Query 1 looks like this :

```
create temporary table test (ordr int, field varchar(1000));

-- Step 1 Create temp table to insert all table/col/json attrbute info

insert into test(ordr,field)
    
    select 0 ordr,'create temporary table temp_table 
    (    table_schema varchar(200)
        ,table_name varchar(200)
        ,column_name varchar(200)
        ,json_attribute varchar(200)
        ,data_type   varchar(50)
    );' 
    
    union

-- Non json type columns

   select 1 ordr, 'insert into temp_table(table_name, column_name,data_type,json_attribute)'
   
   union

-- Json columns with data like json object

    select 
        3 ordr,
        concat('select distinct ''', t.table_name, ''' tbl, ''', c.column_name, ''' col, ''' , c.data_type,''' data_type, '
                ,'jsonb_object_keys(', c.column_name, ') json_attribute', ' from ', t.table_name, 
                ' where jsonb_typeof(' , c.column_name, ') =  ''object'' union') AS field
    from information_schema.tables t
    join information_schema.columns c on c.table_name = t.table_name
    where t.table_schema not in ('information_schema', 'pg_catalog')
        --and table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
        and c.data_type ='jsonb';


--final sql statements to build temp table
--copy all the column "txt" to a separate window and execute it, it will create a temp table "temp_table" which will have all tables/cols/json attributes

    select ordr
        ,(case when t.ordr = (select max(t2.ordr) from test t2) then replace(field,'union','') else field end) txt
    from test t
    union    
    select 9999, ';select * from temp_table;'
    order by 1 ;
```

Query 1 output : This is a list of sql statements

[image]

I'm looking for a way to run the Query 1 & Query 1 output which would get me the final output all in one go.

Any lead or guidance will be really appreciated.

Comment: you can write a shell script and schedule it.

Comment: @ROHITKHURANA I'm looking for a way to do it in Postgres console itself